# error when using php to connect to mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to dynamically build a table on my page through ajax, using jquery and php. The following is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("tbl_name", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Book ISBN` FROM tbl_name");


echo "<table id='booklist'><tr>
                         <th>Edit</th>
                         <th class='coursename'>Course Name</th>
                         <th class='startdate'>Start Date</th>
                         <th class='booktitle'>Book Title</th>
                         <th class='author'>Book Author</th>
                         <th class='isbn'>Book ISBN</th>
                     </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo    "<tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                        <td class='coursename'>" . $row[`Course Name`] . "</td>
                        <td class='startdate'>" . $row[`Start Date`] . "</td>
                        <td class='booktitle'>" . $row[`Book Title`]. "</td>
                        <td class='author'>" . $row[`Book ISBN`]. "</td>
                        <td class='isbn'><input class='ISBN_number' type='text' value='' size='13' maxlength='13'></input></td> 
                  </tr>";                   
        }               
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

(Note: the row names have spaces in them (thats how the database came). I used back ticks instead of single quotes because someone online said thats how you can keep the spaces... If I get over this issue I'll see if that works.)

Next my jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
   {
        $("#build_table").click(function()
        {
            $.get("build_table.php",
                function(table)
                {   console.log("Entered table function");
                    $("#input_table").replaceWith("<div id='input_table'>" + table + "</div>");
                });
        });
   });
```

and the html:

```
<input id="build_table" style="clear:both" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
```

When I click on this button, though, I get the following php error:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:...pathname...\build_table.php on line 13
What is this error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem lies in your query. Are you sure that your database and table is named tbl_name? Change your statement into this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `Book ISBN` FROM tbl_name") or die(mysql_error());
```

And you'll get a error message from MySQL.

Comment: tbl_name is the correct name. But now that I put the error in it does nothing. Where does it record the log? (Oh, and by the way, I'm not sure why it didn't do this before but it does display the headers of the table on the page before it gives the php error...

Comment: It prints it to the browser, so you should see it.

Comment: oh, you're right, it says no database selected... But that is its name! If I go on to phpMyAdmin thats how its listed and if you look at the sql call it makes its the following:  SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_name` 
LIMIT 0 , 30. Why is my database name not correct?

Comment: The database name is not the same as the table name. Can you query `SHOW DATABASES;` in phpMyAdmin and show us the output?

Comment: Yes, I was silly. The database name is really csv_db. I changed that in the mysql_select_db and the sql query went through. But now I have a lot of php errors saying that I have an undefined index, but I got rid of those by using single quotes instead of back ticks... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

run this query this way

```
$sql = "SELECT `Book ISBN` FROM tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
```

and see